# Check if local HTML file exists and load it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to check if an HTML file exists on my local machine.

- If exists → Load the HTML file and display it in browser.
- If not exists → Load and display a PNG file in browser.

Couldn't find documentation for this problem online.

Comment: Are you looking for a javascript code that searches your whole machine?, or just in the project's directory?

Comment: You need to do that using ajax. Check for the file and if the response is 404 then display the image

Comment: front or back end (or node) question? It may not even related to js.

Comment: In-browser JS doesn't have access to the local harddrive. If it did, that would constitute a big security issue.

Comment: @Ramon de Vries Just project directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use the fetch api and to mimic http request for local text files:

```
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('index.html');
  console.log(response.body);
})();
```

Other solution is to use FileReader class

Check this out:
https://www.javascripture.com/FileReader

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `XMLHttpRequest`

```
function LinkCheck(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status != 404;
}
```